# Realizar una query

Tags: php, mysqli

necesito de su orientacion con lo siguiente. como puedo proceder en este caso.

Base de datos.

```
CREATE TABLE `grupos` (
  `grupoid` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `id_usuario` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `gnombre` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `descripcion` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `orden` varchar(11) NOT NULL,
  `activo` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
  `afechas` varchar(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'no',
  `finicio` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `ffinal` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


INSERT INTO `grupos` (`grupoid`, `id_usuario`, `gnombre`, `descripcion`, `orden`, `activo`, `afechas`, `finicio`, `ffinal`) VALUES
(1, 2604, 'Libros', 'Libros es', '1', '1', 'si', '2021-04-06 13:28:24', '2021-04-16 13:28:24'),
(2, 2605, 'Revistas', '', '1', '1', 'si', '2021-04-01 13:28:24', '2021-04-26 13:28:24'),
(3, 2605, 'Cuentos', '', '2', '1', 'no', '0000-00-00 00:00:00', '0000-00-00 00:00:00');
```

Necesito mostrar todos los registros activo "1" y del id_usuario Ej 2605 , pero si tiene la opcion afechas con la opcion "si" validar que aun no estemos en la finicio y que no pase a la ffinal, si esta dentro de las fechas se muestra.

Lo unico que puede lograr desplegar es esto.

```
 
$congrupo = $cont->query("SELECT * FROM grupos WHERE id_usuario = 2605 AND activo = 1 ORDER BY orden+0 ASC");
```

Comment: Puedes aclarar mejor lo de las fechas? Porque en tu consulta no hay nada de eso

Comment: si puedo aclarar, mi consulta no hace nada de eso porque no he logrado harcelo. pero la idea es ..si esta activo afechas validar que finicio eje sea hoy o superior y ffinal que sea igual o menor a hoy.   pero si no tiene la aafecha activo igual mostrar gnombre

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por lo que comentas, parece que te estás refiriendo a algo así:

```
SELECT * FROM grupos 
  WHERE id_usuario=2605 
  AND activo=1 
  AND (
    afechas='no' 
    OR 
    (
      afechas='si'
      AND NOW()>finicio 
      AND NOW()<ffinal
    )
  )
  ORDER BY orden+0 ASC;
```

Comment: MUCHAS GRACIAS!!! eso es lo que necestiaba no puedo valorar tu respuesta. Gracias David.

Comment: Ok, lo que sí que puedes es validar la respuesta y [Gana +2 de reputación](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3762/119615) y, con el [tour] para entender mejor como funcionamos y un voto por tu pregunta, ya tendrás suficiente reputación para comentar y votar. Ánimo, que todo llega...

Answer (score 0):

Entendiendo "no estemos en la finicio" como que es mayor a la fecha de inicio.

```
select * from grupos where (activo = 1 and id_usuario = 2605) and if((afechas = "si" and now() > finicio and now() < ffinal), true, false);
```

Comment: gracias por tu repuesta, pero tengo que mostrar todos los registros, ejemplo del id_usuario = 2605 y si tiene activo afechas hacer la validacion de fechas. agradezco tu respuesta.

Comment: Gracias javier, pero no logro mostra todos los registros

si tengo la opcion no en afechas no deberia hacer validacion de fechas y mostrar todos los registros del id_usuario = 2605 por ejemplo

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que leo en el comentario que haces en la otra respuesta que has dado, necesitas que mostrar todos los registros si o sí. Pero, a la hora de mostrarlos, si uno tiene activo afechas, realizar la comprobación.
Entiendo que el registro con afechas activo, también lo mostraras, pero indicando de alguna manera si la comprobación de fechas es correcta o incorrecta.

Entonces, entendido tu problema de esa manera, no podrías hacer un select de todos los grupos:

```
SELECT * FROM grupos
```

Y luego en php recorrer todos los resultados para ir mostrandolos, y en el momento que vayas a mostrar uno con afechas activo, realizar la comprobación con php?

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM grupos WHERE id_usuario = 2605 AND activo = 1';
$resultado = $conexion->query($query);
while($row = $resultado->fetch_assoc()) {
   $fecha_valida = false;
   $fecha_hoy = date("Y-m-d");
   if($row['afecha'] == 'si'){
       //Afecha es si así que hacemos la comprobación de que sea correcta
       if($fecha_hoy >= $row['finicio'] && $fecha_hoy <= $row['ffinal']){
          $fecha_valida = true;
       }
   }

   ...//En este punto ya sabrías si la entrada tiene afecha activo y si las fechas son validas.
Solamente tendrías que imprimir los datos de cada una de las entradas y en el caso de tener afecha, mostrar si es o no correcta
    if($fecha_valida){
       //imprimir los datos necesarios
    }
}
```

Ten en cuenta que ese código es solamenete un ejemplo, tendrás que implementarlo de manera acorde a tu proyecto.

Comment: Gracias Ibai, pero muestra todos los registros del usuario ej 2605,  aun que aafechas este en si y con fechas "vencidas" igual mustras todo.

Comment: He cambiado un poco el código porque faltaba la validación de si activo = 1 en el query y he añadido algo más, pero de todas formas, como te indico en la respuesta, esto es solo un ejemplo y eres tu el que tendrá que amoldarlo bien a tu proyecto. Aquí estamos para ayudarte e intentar guiarte, pero aquí no estamos para hacer el trabajo de nadie.
Si haces algunas pruebas con mi respuesta o con la de algún otro, estaría bien que nos mostrases que problemas tienes con esa respuesta, como la intentas implementar, y el porque no es valido el resultado, para poder seguir ayudandote.